# Adding <a> tag to App.js Constructor from Component Props

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

## Adding  tag to App.js Constructor from Component Props

Apologies if I'm using the wrong terminology — I'm new'ish to React and JS in general, but pretty confident in my HTML and CSS skills. JS, let alone React, was always SUPER intimidating for me but decided to learn it as a New Year's resolution and so far I'm glad I did!

I've been looking for a solution to my dilemma but can't seem to find a solution (I'm sure there is, I just haven't found one or not grasping React Router).

So I'm using React Router to navigate to other pages on my app (site), but can't seem to find a way to add a link inside a body of copy, as you would in HTML:

`<p>Morbi leo risus, porta <a href="www.someaddress.com">Link Label</a>, vestibulum at ero.</p>`

Based on the research I've done, it's best to use an anchor tag when navigating users to pages outside my application, and I'm able to do so if I enter copy and a link within my component, but then that defeats the purpose of a componentized system. I've explored solutions Linkify, but that still doesn't allow me to enter a link inside my content block in app.js — hope I'm explaining this correctly.

The only solution I could figure out was to do this in my contentBlock.js component:

`` <p>{paragraphStart} {<a href={`${linkAddress}`}>{linkLabel}</a>} {paragraphEnd}</p> ``

This seems kind of hacky and not intuitive — thanks for the help.

Example code below:

### Component Code:

```
//React
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//React Router
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

//React Router Hash Link: add anchor to same/seperate page/section.
//https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link
// import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';

//Animate CSS: add class to element to animate when loading page/module.
import '../css/tools/animate/animate.min.css';
import '../css/tools/hover/hover.css';

//Animate on Scroll CSS: add data-aos="animationName" and data-aos-once="true/false" to animate only once per load or both directions.
import AOS from 'aos';
import 'aos/dist/aos.css';

class ContentBlock extends Component {
    render () {
    const {heading, paragraph, button, image, imageSmall, imageMedium, imageLarge, imageExtraLarge, altText} = this.props;
    return(
            <div className="container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-once="true">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="contentBlock">
                        <img src={`../assets/${image}.jpg`} srcSet={`../assets/${imageSmall}.jpg 576w, ../assets/${imageMedium}.jpg 768w, ../assets/${imageLarge}.jpg 992w, ../assets/${imageExtraLarge}.jpg 1200w`} class="img-fluid col-12 col-lg-6"alt={`${altText}`}></img>
                        <div className="copy col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <h2>{heading}</h2>
                            <hr class="hrBrand"/>
                            <p>{paragraph}</p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn outline">{button}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

// Animate on Scroll init
AOS.init();

export default ContentBlock;
```

### App.js

```
<ContentBlock 
image="img-speaker"
imageSmall="img-speaker"
imageMedium="img-speaker"
imageLarge="img-speaker"
imageExtraLarge="img-speaker"
altText="Smart speaker next to tv."
heading="Some awesome heading" 
paragraph="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
button="Button Label" 
/>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, one option could be to create a new component that would parse your `paragraph` prop and assign a [**<Link>**](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) to specific text.

Answer (score 0):

Smart TV's don't support `<a>` tag functionality. You need to handle keypress using onKeydown() and then handle the navigation accordingly.

```
`useEffect(() => {
    window.onkeydown = (e) => {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case ENTER: {
          backButton.current.focus();
          navigate('/');
          break;
        }
        case BACK: {
          window.history.back();
          break;
        }
        case UP: {
          // Up functionality handled here.
          break;
        }
        default: 
          break;
      }
    }
  }, []);`
```

Above is the sample code to handle navigation on Smart TV's.